# Android: different sharing depending on the app

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing

I need to implemented a sharing for my app.

The thing is that the customer wants me to implement this in a way that if the user taps "Facebook", a certain text, image, url, description, etc will be shared, while for example if he taps on twitter, a certain string shorter than 140 chars will be written.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I run into this post [Android share intent chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431386/android-share-intent-chooser) which says that there's no way to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: what is the problem with intent chooser

Comment: You can implement your own chooser with a bit of work then get to do something different based on the result.  In my case I just wanted to put the choice into the analitics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Not readily, mostly because from Android's standpoint, there is no Facebook, and there is no Twitter.

Facebook and Twitter are Web sites. They also have APIs/SDKs, leading to Android apps. The key is that there are *apps*, plural. Twitter themselves has more than one app that they have published, let alone third-party clients.

You have no way of knowing whether or not there are any apps for Web site XYZ installed. Some complete idiots will say "oh, just check for this-and-so package name". Even if this-and-so package name exists, there is no evidence that the user uses it -- it might be preinstalled and unable to be removed, so it lingers. And, there is no guarantee that the official app will keep this-and-so package name forever, or will support sharing content via `ACTION_SEND` the same ways forever, etc.

You are certainly welcome to have your app share multiple types of things. However, the user will need to choose the *type* of thing first, *then* choose *any* app that supports that type. If the user wants to use "a certain string shorter than 140 chars" with Facebook, or Gmail, or Evernote, instead of Twitter, that is *their choice*. You could roll your own chooser, that presents the `ACTION_SEND` apps and then have the user choose what to send, but since you have no idea if what they chose happens to be a Twitter client or not, you cannot reliably tailor the content to the underlying Web site.